# How can I assign a javascript variable in html format?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, there is a page like below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Variables!!!</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lookatthis = 11;
var one = 22;
var two = 3;
var add = one + two;
var minus = one - two;
var multiply = one * two;
var divide = one/two;
    document.write("First No: = " + one + "<br />Second No: = " + two + " <br />");
    document.write(one + " + " + two + " = " + add + "<br/>");
    document.write(one + " - " + two + " = " + minus + "<br/>");
    document.write(one + " * " + two + " = " + multiply + "<br/>");
    document.write(one + " / " + two + " = " + divide + "<br/>");
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to assign the javascript variable "lookatthis" on debug console.

//apologise for my ambiguous question. I would rather say,
"I want to assign new value to variable "lookatthis" on this web-page using console on explorer."

Thank you for your kind teaching.)

Comment: put a debugger and then assign it from the console. What difficulty do you face in that?

Comment: If it's an input then it's `Element.value = lookatthis;`, otherwise it's `Element.innerHTML = lookatthis;`. `Element` can be gotten, via `document.getElementById('yourHTMLidHere')` or any number of DOM methods. Make sure you escape `.innerHTML` special characters. Refrain from using `document.write` whenever possible *(which is always)*.

Answer (score 1):

Open debug [console](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/232313848-How-to-open-the-developer-console) and write there:

```
lookatthis = 20
```

But this get you nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `log` method:

```
console.log(lookatthis);
```

Comment: OP wants to assign the variable, not print it

Comment: From the "variety" of answers we can deduce that the question indeed is unclear. So we will wait the decision of the asker to accept (perhaps) one the answers and clear the doubts. :)

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere in your script block after your initial assignment of lookatthis, you can write the value to the console with the command:

console.log(lookatthis);

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to be able to 'set' the value of lookatthis, you can use an input and using jquery or pure js get the value of the input and assign it to 'lookatthis'.

Edit: You can also use in the chrome console: `lookatthis=25`
but as your script loads when page loads, changes will not be shown but the value will be changed

Answer (score 0):

You achieve it by using prompt function

```
var lookatthis = prompt('Type the lokaltthis value');
```